# Stop snapping from occuring with inserted text?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping

I'm having trouble with text and scale bars in layout mode on arcgis snapping. I want to move the text freely. It's not necessarily snapping to inserted margins either. I've tried guides and it won't fix the problem. I've turned off snapping and that hasn't done anything. I also hold the space bar/shift and that won't work. Lastly, I tried converting to graphics and that didn't do anything. Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: The Snapping Toolbar only applies to geographic features in your map, not layout elements.  Midavalo's answer below shows the options you have for lining things up for layout elements like text and scale bars. I tend to do my layouts with all of the "snap elements to" options in the screenshot below turned off except for the grid, set to 0.1 or 0.25 in.  That way things line up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcMap you can set text and graphic elements to snap to different things to help line things up.  This is controlled in the Layout tab of your **ArcMap Options** window (click Customize > ArcMap Options).

You possibly want to test the different **Snap elements to** options to find which option needs to be turned off.  Possibly the **Grid** option.

[image]